# Find a cubic function given the inflection point and minimal point

Tags: derivatives, cubics, extreme-value-theorem

I came across this task that I just couldn't figure out.

The task gave me an extremum(1,1) and the inflection point(2,3), and I need to figure out the cubic function given the values.

Assuming the cubic function would look like `f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d`, the following is what I've done so far:

```
a+b+c+d = 1 (y for extremum)
8a+4b+2c+d = 3 (y for inflection point)
```

Derivative function's 0 for the extremum:

```
3a+2b+c = 0
```

Second derivative's 0 for the inflection point:

```
12a+2b=0
```

After this, I just can't figure out, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have four equations and four unknowns. Solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write all the variables in terms of $a$ and solve as follows:

$$12a + 2b = 0 \implies b = -6a$$

$$\therefore \, 3a + 2(-6a) + c = 0 \implies c = 9a$$

$$\therefore \, a + (-6a) + (9a) + d = 1 \implies d = 1 - 4a$$

$$\therefore \, 8a + 4(-6a) + 2(9a) + (1 - 4a) = 3 \implies a = -1$$

$$\therefore \, a = -1, \, b = 6, \, c = -9, \, d = 5$$

Hence, we get $f(x) = -x^3 + 6x^2 - 9x + 5$.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out :) Had done the same approach at the start but instead I put 6*2 as 18 instead of 12...

Answer (score 1):

As $(2,3)$ is the inflection point we have
$$f(x)=a(x-2)^3+b(x-2)+3.$$
From $(1,1)$ we get $-a-b+1=1$.  Now from $f'(x)=3a(x-2)^2+b$ we get $3a+b=0$, that is
$$f(x)=-(x-2)^3+3(x-2)+3.$$